# KeyCode not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, random

I'm making a game that has got an array, which represents an island, and this array should be randomly generated each time you start the game (I'll make the procedurally generated part when it will be finished). Also, if you click the arrows or wasd, it should make you see parts of the island that you couldn't. But I have a problem: when I click the key, nothing happens.

Here's the code for the movement (it's on three different classes):

```
 //class Form
 private Game game = new Game();
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    public GameWindow()
    {
        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(GameWindow_KeyDown);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void GameWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            y = -1;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            x = -1;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            y = 1;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        game.Move(x, y);
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        game.startGraphics(g, 100);
    }

    private void GameWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        game.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
        game.Move(x, y); // I put this to see if it works, but it still does nothing
    }
// class Game
public void Move(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x == -1 && gEngine.smallestXTileOnScreen == 0) { }
        else if (x == 1 && gEngine.smallestXTileOnScreen == size - 25) { }
        else if (y == -1 && gEngine.smallestYTileOnScreen == 0) { }
        else if (y == 1 && gEngine.smallestYTileOnScreen == size - 15) { }
        else
        {
            gEngine.smallestXTileOnScreen += x;
            gEngine.smallestYTileOnScreen += y;
            gEngine.render();
        }
    }
//class GraphEngine
public void render()
    {
        drawHandle.Clear(Color.Blue);
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
            {
                prop = world[i + smallestXTileOnScreen , j + smallestYTileOnScreen];
                switch (prop)
                {
                    case 0:
                        drawHandle.DrawImage(sea, i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        drawHandle.DrawImage(plain, i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        drawHandle.DrawImage(mountain, i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        drawHandle.DrawImage(valley, i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
                        break;
                    default:
                        drawHandle.DrawImage(sea, i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        Form Debug = new Form(); //Notice that I put here a form, if it's shown,
        Debug.Show();//then render() has been called. It doesn't show.
    }
```

EDIT: I put the entire code of the first class, maybe it could help you... I don't know what should I do, I'm new to Visual Studio :/

Comment: `world[i, j] = r.Next(0, 3);` How random do you really think this can be?

Comment: All of your `Random`s have the same seed.

Comment: Create random instance at the begging, outside of loops.

Comment: @Scott, you have read only part of the question, haven't you?

Comment: I've now modified it, and it now contains one unanswered question :)

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in `GameWindow_KeyDown` does it get hit?

Comment: Surely the new window doesn't show for the same reason your KeyDown event never fires.  You are not making sure that the Windows notifications are dispatched.  Either use Application.Run() with a 16 msec Timer that calls move/render or use Application.DoEvents() inside your game loop.  Google "windows forms game loop" to learn more.

Comment: It does nothing... KeyDown never fires, and neither Application.Run() nor Application.DoEvents() do anything... I tried putting `KeyPreview = true;
            KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(GameWindow_KeyDown);`

Comment: Just for fun, try putting `InitializeComponent()` first in the method. In general, one should _add_ to generated code.

Comment: well, done, but it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason it seems that my version of Visual Studio C# 2010 is a bit buggy. I had to go to the \bin\Debug folder and empty it before doing the debug, and it works with the normal code + the keyPreview = true... hope it's just a bug :/